# How did Luke 17:33 associate with Lot's wife?

Tags: luke

It appears that Luke 17:32 and 17:33 are associated context. If so, how Lot's wife was used as an example to explain 17:33?

> 32 Remember Lot’s wife!
>
> 33 Whoever tries to keep their life will lose it, and whoever loses their life will preserve it. (NIV)

Comment: This question requires clarification - I cannot understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Dottard - Question had been edited

Answer (score 1):

“Losing life” in this, to use this ugly word, “positive” way, or, to use this more appropriate word, salvific way, means a conversion from sinfulness and worldliness to gracefulness and heavenliness through letting the Lord Jesus Christ to dwell and work in our hearts together with the Father and Holy Spirit. Thus a believer is commanded to dare a full conversion from old Adam to Christ - the New Adam (1 Cor. 15:45), i.e. lose his soul for Christ (Mark 8:35).

Now, Lot’s wife looked back, which symbolizes a person who did not convert wholeheartedly but left a secret space in heart for return to sinful delectation and worldly interest over against the heavenly interest. Such a person only outwardly lost his soul for Christ, while innerly still is attached to the realm of sin and worldliness. Such a person is not trustworthy and does not qualify for visa into the best Kingdom (Luke 9:62), that of the Father and the Son and the Holy Ghost.

Comment: Thanks Levan for the answer. It is a typical theological exploration. But in the era of Abraham, they didn't have the knowledge as we are today. Should they be judged differently? The angels didn't give Lot's family a hard warning, such as God told Adam and Eve that "you must not eat the fruit" or "you will die". Also it only answers "whoever tries to keep their life will lose it", and what about "whoever loses their life will preserve it"?

Comment: @VincentWong Thanks. The last quote is implied in the previous: whoever will deny his earthly and sinful inclinations for the sake of the Lord and His commandments will preserve the soul for exactly in Lord is any soul’s true and blissful life, the eternal life.

Answer (score 1):

Lot's wife is related to the following verse because she was wishing to save her old life, the life she loved in the city with her friends, and looked back to the city against the angels' command that had been given her.  For this she lost her life, and was turned into a pillar of salt. (You will find the story in Genesis 19.)

In desiring to preserve her comfortable life, not being willing to give up her possessions, her friends, her family -- she lost even her own life.

Jesus wants us to commit to following him completely, being willing to give up everything of value in exchange for the more valuable relationship we might have with him.  Being willing to lose everything in this world for God's sake is what is necessary to see our lives saved in the end.

It's an irony of life that Jesus used Lot's wife to help illustrate.

Comment: "*she was wishing to save her old life*" is perhaps too strong. Simply feeling bad about what she was willingly giving up would be enough. Similarly, when accepting God's way, one shouldn't have any nostalgia for one's previous life.

Comment: @RayButterworth Except that in her case one might truly question how "willingly" she was leaving.  Remember that the angels had taken them each by the hand and had led them out of the city in a rather compelling fashion. _"And while he lingered, the men laid hold upon his hand, and upon the hand of his wife, and upon the hand of his two daughters; the LORD being merciful unto him: and they brought him forth, and set him without the city." (Gen. 19:16)._  They had lingered and dilly-dallied until finally the angels took it into their own hands.  Lot's own delay proved his wife's downfall.

Comment: @Biblasia - Lot did not want the angels spent the night in the square. When the men of Sodom came to his house, he suggested to exchange his two daughters for the safety of the angels. Did you believe a place like this was comfortable? Even if your understanding was right, it only answers "whoever tries to keep their life will lose it", and what about "whoever loses their life will preserve it". Did the men die in Sodom preserved their lives?

Comment: @VincentWong I may not be understanding your question. When the angels first came to him, he did not know they were angels. They looked like men. He tried to protect them. But by the time the angels had worked the miracle to defeat the mob outside his home, it was clear that his guests were no ordinary visitors. At the point where the angels took him from the city, he certainly knew the angels were protecting _him_, not the other way around. But his home, his belongings, his money, his livelihood, his friends, his memories, **his family** were all there, to be sadly given up and left behind.

Comment: @Biblasia - try thinking in this angle. Who would be willing to give up his daughters for strangers? Would Lot somehow know these two were not ordinary men right away when he saw them? If God knew there did not have more than 10 righteous people in Sodom, did Lot not knowing he was in a danger city?  Your interpretation of "But his home.........sadly given up" did not have scripture support. Again, how does her story answer "whoever loses their life will preserve it"?.

Comment: @VincentWong Lot had made his home in Sodom.  That was where he lived.  That is Biblical. Consider Gen. 14:11-12.  Lot, and his possessions, had been taken along with others from Sodom.  And it was because he lived in Sodom that the Sodomite men had come to his home to demand access to his guests.  Giving up the daughters (or it might even have been his wife) was more customary of those times than it would be today (read the story in Judges 19).  This story shows how depraved the Sodomites were, to refuse what they were offered in pursuit of homosexual lust instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to Ellicott's Commentary in biblehub.com

> (32) Remember Lot’s wife.—The reference to this, as to the history of Lot generally, is peculiar to St. Luke, and speaks strongly for the independence of his Gospel. The account of Lot’s wife had, however, already been used, or was used shortly afterwards (the date of the Wisdom of Solomon being an unsettled problem), to point a like moral, and the “standing pillar of salt” had become “a monument of an unbelieving soul” (Wisdom Of Solomon 10:7). She had looked back, as the disciples were told not to look, and the glance had been fatal (Genesis 19:26).

Wisdom of Solomon 10:7 read

> Of whose wickedness even to this day the waste land that smoketh is a testimony, and plants bearing fruit that never come to ripeness: and a standing pillar of salt is a monument of an unbelieving soul. (Brenton Septuagint Translation)

According to Britannica, the Book - Wisdom of Solomon, was written by a Jew in Alexandria sometime during the 1st century BC, the book was in effect a defense of Judaism, for, in describing Jewish doctrines in terms of Hellenistic philosophy.

Though it is unknown to me if the Pharisees adopted this book that was written in Greek into their doctrine. As teachers of the law, it might be fair the book was known to the Pharisees. Or in the Jews circle, they recognized that the term "Lot's wife" represent "a monument of an unbelieving soul".

In Luke 17:33, The word "life" in Greek is ψυχὴν (Psuche), unlike another Greek word of life "Bios" that refers to the life of the physical body, Psuche refers to the psychological life of the human soul, that is, the mind, emotion and will. The Recovery Version Study Bible translates Psuche as "soul-life" to distinguish it from "Bios".

There is a third Greek word "Zoe" also mean "life". It refers to the uncreated, eternal life of God, the divine life uniquely possessed by God. It had been used in John 1:1-4,14.

So Luke was playing with words here. Review again Luke 17:32-33

> 32 Remember Lot’s wife!
>
> 33 Whoever tries to keep their life will lose
> it, and whoever loses their life will preserve it.

We might elaborate it as

> 32 Remember Lot's wife, her unbelieving soul;
>
> 33 Whoever tries to keep their "soul-life" will lose "zoe" (it), and whoever loses their "soul-life" will preserve "zoe" (it)

Luke used a pronoun "it" to hide the ultimate "zoe" a believer is looking for. And the unbelieving souls will only keep their "soul-life", a human soul that is not godly.